# css. centering text inside a label, but ignore the input

Tags: css, drupal

So I basically have a `label` and text like this:

```
<label class="labelClass"> for="something">
    <input id="inputID" class="inputClass" name="inputName" value="value" type="radio">
    Some text inside the label.
</label>
```

Note that this is just an `example` and not used for any other means.

---

So I can and know how to call to this `label` and `input`, but They keep looking like this:

[image: The problem]

I already tried:

- `margin-right`
- `padding` & `padding-right`
- `text-align:center`

Like in the following `css` example:

```
.page-to-the-css label.something.option {
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and also for the `radio` button:

```
.page-to-the-css input.something.inputClass {
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

Hope anyone could help me solve this problem.

Note: I also can't touch the `jquery`, `javascript` or anything else but `css`, so keep it at `css` please.

UPDATE: Neither did any of the current answers work, also not the one of VilleKoo.

EDIT: This is the form it is happening to: [form](http://dev.grofkeramiek.nl/form/excursie-opgave-formulier) This website is `drupal` so I can't reach the `html` or sadly I can't provide you guys of any `code`. I hope this problem could be solved either way.

Comment: How about adding some margin?

Comment: @Swellar I tried adding `margin`, but the margin gets completely ignored.

Comment: You need to provide us with the css that is not working - as your code is at the moment, it wouldn't display like you show in the picture.  Help us to replicate the problem so we can help you fix it - see [MCVE].  The only problem I currently see is your label is closed a bit early

Comment: @KingReload we need the code to replicate your current error.  If you do not provide us with that then we cannot help you, read the link I have provided in the above comment and try editing again

Comment: @pete I can't give the current code as it's in the development, I can't reach the html neither did I write any css to solve this. Basically saying I can only show an example.

Comment: @Pete I linked the form of the website to where it is happening to. If that provides the information you need

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: You've declared 3 times margin for the input element.

Comment: @VilleKoo that's just the code I tried so far. But I tried your answer as it seemed reasonable, sadly it didn't help, but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: What i mean is that you have margin declared here and there and it's overriding what you want to achieve. This is what you have going on there right now: https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/59cm3k76/

Comment: @VilleKoo I know :( sadly I can't adapt it in the module, as the module must be updatable still. The margin I currently use does apply to the `radio` button, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Can't you just remove that margin-left: 0px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input { 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<label id="labelID" for="something">
    <input id="inputID" class="inputClass" name="inputName" value="value" type="radio">
    Some text inside the label.
</label>
<label id="labelID" for="something">
    <input id="inputID" class="inputClass" name="inputName" value="value" type="radio">
    Some text inside the label.
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look my example, it is easy

```css
.labelClass {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.labelClass .inputClass {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="labelClass" for="something">
    <input id="inputID" class="inputClass" name="inputName" value="value" type="radio">
    Some text inside the label.
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Many HTML elements have a default margin setting. You can override this and set it to 0. In your case, you want to reset margin-right on the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" style="margin-right: 0" />
```

You probably want to add it to your stylesheet so that it applies to all radio buttons:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: than you need to check all the css classes that calling it